# How well are the energy differences between ortho and para hydrogen and deuterium known

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, hydrogen

For a while i have been investigating whether neutrinos could feel a fifth force, that is axial, (opposite charge for opposite spin). But charge conservation means that either proton and neutron are also charged, as the diffence is the neutrino charge. Follows by conversation of charge in beta decay. So this would mean the axial force would show up in the energies difference between ortho hydrogen and para hydrogen, (hydrogen with proton spins aligned (ortho) and opposed (para). If the proton doesn't have a charge the neutron will, so it could also show up energy difference between ortho and para deuterium. How well are the ortho para energy differences known for hydrogen and deuterium, and how well does that meet current predictions. Is there experimental room for a new force here.

Original paper (unpublished) http://chirality.yolasite.com/resources/paper/axial.pdf

Comment: Reviewers of this question should note that while the *motivation* for this question probably isn't a good fit for our [policy on non-mainstream physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539), the question itself, about precision measurements in molecular energy levels, is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: *Is there experimental room for a new force here ?* This seems opinion based and is wandering into non-mainstream physics.  Almost all the question (including the link to the unpublished paper) would seem off topic except the part mentioned by @rob .  A drastic edit is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wondering about an axial force that gives applies an energy shift to interactions where spin orientations are reversed. But that doesn't require a fifth force --- the weak nuclear force has a mixture of vector and axial-vector interactions, and therefore gives different energies for interactions depending on their spins.  The data you are asking about would be indistinguishable from a weak interaction influence on the hydrogen molecules.

However, the weak force is so feeble compared to the strong and electromagnetic forces that the energy shifts it induces are almost never directly measureable.
Instead people look for mixing between states with opposite parity.  In complicated systems where there are states with the same spin and opposite parity that are nearly degenerate in energy, there may be enhanced parity mixing due to the weak interaction.
For example, there's a nuclear transition (a strong-interaction transition) in lanthanum with a 10% parity-violating signal.
But without any such enhancement, the "natural size" of such parity-violating interactions is about $10^{-7}$.
Just detecting such tiny asymmetries is very challenging: the typical timescale for an experiment is a decade.
[This review](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.nucl.54.070103.181255) of low-energy nuclear weak interactions, including neutron-proton and proton-proton interactions, is more than a decade old now but has only missed a couple of new results.

To your specific question about molecular hydrogen energy levels:  those systems are not constrained at the level you ask about (yay for you) and probably never will be (boo for you) because the structure of the energy levels is wrong.  Pauli symmetry demands that hydrogen and deuterium have a strict relationship between orbital angular momentum in the molecule and the alignment of the nuclear spins.  The energy levels are

$$
E_L = \frac{E_1}2 L (L+1)
$$

where for hydrogen the states with even $L$ have $S=0$, the odd $L$ have $S=1$, and the energy scale is $E_1 \approx 15\rm\, meV$. (For deuterium, where each nucleus is a boson rather than a fermion, the even states have $S=0,2$ and the odd have $S=1$, and the energy scale is comparable.)
This system isn't complicated enough to have the nearly-degenerate opposite-parity energy levels that would enhance the sort of signal you're looking for, so the parity mixing would be at the hard-to-measure un-enhanced level.  (In fact the weak interaction prediction would be many orders of magnitude smaller; the $10^{-7}$ asymmetries are "natural" for strong interactions where the nucleons touch each other.)
Furthermore if there *were* any spin-related energy level shift, it'd be much easier to explain using the weak interaction that we already know about rather than proposing a new interaction entirely.

If you read the review I linked above you'll learn that the theoretical interpretation of experimental results in this area (that is, evidence for axial-vector forces in the form of parity violation in low-energy nuclear reactions) is actually kind of a mess.
A committed optimist might interpret this as room for a new interaction.
However, the consensus in the community is that the problem lies in our understanding of the strong interaction and that there's plenty of room for the interactions we already know about to explain this data.

Comment: Thanks, can i have you permission to link to this answer from my blog

Comment: It's very polite of you to ask permission to link, but not really necessary. If you read the [fine print](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service), content on these sites is published under a [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, which gives you considerable (but not unlimited) freedom to use it.